# What was the first systematic book about Jewish tradition?

Tags: history, jewish-books

If I follow Rabbinic sources from the Torah to Rambam, I spot a progression from essentially unstructured and non-systematic books such as the Tanakh to Midrashic anthologies and Halachic compendia, e.g the Mishna and the Talmud, that, while organized by topics or Parashot, do not present a consistent and coherent view on any subject, and to Rambam's Mishne Torah as an attempt to systematize all the existing Halachic knowledge by Mitzvos, chapters, and books.

On this timeline, what was the first book that attempted a systematic approach to Jewish knowledge and tradition?

*(Maybe I'm wrong about the progression, and Rambam was unique in his approach).*

Comment: What makes a book systematic? Organization by topic instead of by Torah-verse sources? The Mishna is organized by topic and has chapters.

Comment: Probably Reb Saadia Gaon

Comment: Why do you not consider the Mishnah to be systematic?

Comment: @DoubleAA IMHO, systematic means having a system for covering a topic, like defining the 613 Mitzvos first, dividing them all into books, and then discussing each one without leaving out any of them. Mishna is very unsystematic, as it does not mention many Mitzvos at all and jumps from one topic to another within a chapter, mixes Halochos and stories, etc. Even the tractates within a Seder are arranged by the most chapters and not its content.

Comment: The [systematic approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Kalam) you mention is due to [Islamic influence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam), and Judaism is by no means the only religious faith it inspired, with similar schools of thought, such as Roman Catholic [scholasticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholasticism), appearing within medieval Christianity as well.